# Weird GL_INVALID_OPERATION error in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

```
glClearColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );

AttachVertexShader( shader, "szescian_vs.glsl" );
AttachFragmentShader( shader, "szescian_fs.glsl" );
LinkProgram( shader );

glBindVertexArray( vertexVAO );

glGenBuffers( 1, &positionBuffer );

glGenBuffers( 1, &positionBuffer );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( position ), position, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
positionLoc = glGetAttribLocation( shader, "inPosition" );
glEnableVertexAttribArray ( positionLoc );
glVertexAttribPointer ( positionLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ( void* ) 0 ); //here gDEBugger GL breaks on OpenGL Error
```

It's part of my init function, and I really don't know why gDEBugger breaks on it, can anybody explain it for me?

> Break Reason    OpenGL Error Breaked-on    glVertexAttribPointer(0 , 3
>   , GL_FLOAT , FALSE , 0 , 0x00000000) Error-Code
>   GL_INVALID_OPERATION Error-Description    The specified operation is
>   not allowed in the current state. The offending function is ignored,
>   having no side effect other than to set the error flag.
>   * Stopped before function execution

This is break information.

Comment: My guess would be that ( void* ) 0 is a pointer to the memory at 0x00000000 which may not be accessed since it is the beginning of the memory and should be reserved

Comment: I'm not much with openGL. But what do the docs say about each parameter and its purpose?

Comment: @Xtroce No, that pointer is interpreted as an offset into the currently bound buffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The possible `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` errors generated by `glVertexAttribPointer()`:

1. `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if size is `GL_BGRA` and type is not
   `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV` or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV`.
2. `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if type is `GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV`
   or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV` and size is not 4 or `GL_BGRA`.
3. `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if type is
   `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10F_11F_11F_REV` and size is not 3.
4. `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated by `glVertexAttribPointer` if size
   is `GL_BGRA` and noramlized is `GL_FALSE`.
5. `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if zero is bound to the
   `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` buffer object binding point and the pointer argument
   is not `NULL`.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml